# How to load an array from a file with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, file-io

I have a file which has an array of hashes in it:

```
[
  {key1: 'value', key2: 'value'},
  {key1: 'value', key2: 'value'},
  {key1: 'value', key2: 'value'}
  ...
]
```

I would like to load this entire array into a variable and make some manipulations with it. To be super concrete, I'd like to re-arrange the array alphabetically based on the key1. Read, readlines and each_line not working for me.

Comment: That's JSON data. Use the [JSON library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) to parse it, then manipulate the resulting object as you would with any array of hashes in Ruby.

Comment: Can you show the code you've got so far that attempts to read this, and the errors you're receiving?

Comment: @PaulRichter I don't understand the very basic command required to treat the entire content of a file as an array. I've spent a couple of hours googling and this is my last resort. I don't need 'my homework' to be done by someone else, so just a link to an appropriate article will do

Comment: @DenisG You wrote that *Read, readlines and each_line* are not working for you. It is reasonable to assume you have made an attempt to solve this problem, and it is not presently functioning the way you want. I am asking to see that attempt, and to see the errors you're receiving. I'm perfectly willing to accept that you've done research on this, and nowhere did I ask about homework, or accuse you of posting a *gimmeh teh codez*-type question; if you want help about a problem you're facing, you're going to need to be ready to give people the additional information they ask for.

Comment: @DenisG - Would you consider changing the format of this file? It is recommended to sotre data like that in yam files.

Comment: @BroiSatse sure, easily

Comment: @Ajedi32: That is not JSON, JSON requires quotes around the keys. It may be *JavaScript* but it certainly isn't *JSON*.

Comment: @muistooshort Good point. It's valid YAML though, so that would work instead I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of rule, `Hash.to_s` is a one-way function - there is no easy way to parse it. Given that the format is plain, and as you stated, you can do something like this:

```
text = IO.read('test.txt')

# normalize text to a valid JSON:

# turns 'value' to "value"
text.gsub!("'", '"')
# turns key1: to "key1":
text.gsub!(/([{,])\s*([^{":\s]+)\s*:/, '\1 "\2":')

#parse it
array = JSON.parse(text)

sorted = array.sort_by { |h| h['key1'] }
# => [{"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value"}, {"key1"=>"value2", "key2"=>"value"}, {"key1"=>"value3", "key2"=>"value"}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Since your file is valid Ruby, if it's from a trusted source you can just `eval` it:

```
my_sorted_array = eval(IO.read('test.txt')).sort_by { |e| e[:key1] }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to store such a data in yaml format. Write the file like (mind the spacing!):

```
---
- :key1: value
  :key2: value
- :key1: value
  :key2: value
- :key1: value
  :key2: value
```

Then just do:

```
require 'yaml'
array = YAML.parse_file('/path/to/your/file')
```

To save data to such a file (`require 'yaml'` needed to run this as well):

```
File.open('/path/to/file', 'w') { |f| f.write array.to_yaml }
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the following:

```
require 'yaml'
data = YAML.load_file '<filename>'
data.sort_by{|hash| hash[:key1]}
```

Your file looks quite a bit like JSON data, but includes a few minor formatting differences that make using a JSON parser impossible. Thankfully the data is perfectly valid YAML, so Ruby's YAML parser can read it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

```
str = ""
File.open('<path_to_file>').each do |line|
  str += line.strip
end
hash_array = eval(str)
hash_array.sort_by!{|t| t[:key1]}
```

Sorry about the prior answer.

Comment: As Uri said. If you're using a library which adds this functionality, you should include this in your post.

Comment: Just corrected it. Sorry about that. Implemented something similar in a to_h function a while back, and I just kind of assume that everything has it.

Comment: Agreed, although from the sound of it, he is running it on a local file, so I doubt that it's a risk.